# Python / Selenium Find first instances of elements

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to copy search result tables from a website into an excel sheet
But the data isn't very clean and it's causing some issues with outputting the lists into a pandas dataframe.

There is 15 columns of data, but the last 2 have blank headers and 2 of them have duplicate headers. Which (I think) is causing me to get this error "ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length"

Realistically I only need the first 9 columns of the table which in this case means there won't be any duplicate or blank headers in the data anymore.

Is there a way to limit find_elements to get the first 9 columns of the table rather than all columns? Or to fix the headers so that there are no longer any duplicates or blanks?

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

```
for x in result:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sidemenu"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/form/div[2]/input[1]').send_keys(x)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navsrch"]').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    headers = []
    columns = dict()

    table_id = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'invoice')
    all_rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

    row = all_rows[0]
    all_items = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "th")
    for item in all_items:
        name = item.text
        columns[name] = []
        headers.append(name)

    print(headers)

    for row in all_rows[1:]:
        all_items = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
        for name, item in zip(headers, all_items):
            value = item.text
            columns[name].append(value)

    print(columns)
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
    print(df)

driver.close()
```

Comment: If you want to limit the number of iterations thru you could use a while loop. I'm not aware of a limit in selenium like you are describing. Could you post some screen shots or something so I can better see the tables?

Comment: Hi Aaron here is a screenshot of the table and the html source of the headers & rows https://imgur.com/a/zHSTlzD

Comment: position()<=9 Is a simple xpath addition. So something like .//tr[position()<=9]

Comment: Can you confirm the url of the page you are trying to scrape?

Comment: You won't be able to access the url, it requires a login that I won't be able to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue by looping through the specificed amount of times that I needed and iterating the xpath position each loop and sending the data straight to excel on each loop. Thanks for your help Aaron for the iterating idea & Arundeep for the xpath position idea.

```
for x in result:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sidemenu"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/form/div[2]/input[1]').send_keys(x)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navsrch"]').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    row = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="invoice"]/tbody/tr')
    lrow = len(row) + 1

    for i in range(1, lrow):
        l_e_r = len(list(ws.rows)) + 1
        for y in range(1, 10):
            rows = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="invoice"]/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td['+str(y)+']').text
            ws.cell(row=l_e_r, column=y).value = rows


wb.save("test.xlsx")
driver.close()
```